# How to get job name via flink rest api?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying to monitor the status of flink jobs by their names.

But I did not find any rest api could return the job name from this [site](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/rest_api.html).

How can I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`GET /jobs`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/rest_api.html#jobs) only returns the job id and status.

[`GET /jobs/overview`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/rest_api.html#jobs-overview) returns the detailed messages, like id, name, status.